# Super weird issue where typescript/javascript behavior on staging environment differs from localhost

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, typescript

Here's an example of the code I have:

```
function getDefault() {
  return {
    foo: 'a'
  }
}

function getBar() {
  bar: any = getDefault();
  bar.bar = 'b';
}

function getCat() {
  cat: any = getDefault();
  cat.cat = 'c';
}

...
console.log(getBar());
console.log(getCat());
```

This code outputs the following when I run locally:

```
{ foo: 'a', bar: 'b' }
{ foo: 'a', cat: 'c' }
```

But when I run this on my staging environment, I get the following:

```
{ foo: 'a', bar: 'b', cat: 'c' }
{ foo: 'a', bar: 'b', cat: 'c' }
```

Super weird. In order to fix this I modified the functions to call getDefault like this `{...getDefault()}`:

```
function getBar() {
  bar: any = {...getDefault()};
  bar.bar = 'b';
}

function getCat() {
  cat: any = {...getDefault()};
  cat.cat = 'c';
}
```

Basically I'm explicitly cloning the object returned by getDefault().

Anyone understand why this might be happening? I'm using `tsc` to transpile typescript and webpack to bundle.

Comment: What are the typescript versions used? What is transpilation target?

Comment: @clu is that contained in a class?